# writeDatagram() was called not in QAbstractSocket::BoundState or QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState

Tags: c++, qt, сокет, клиент-сервер, udp

Создаю QT клиент-серверное приложение, которое бы по нажатию на кнопку отправляло бы сообщение всем клиентам по протоколу UDP. В качестве отправной точки использовал туториал на Youtube:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qx4FaglSig. Пошагово повторял действия автора:

Файл myudp.h:

```
#ifndef MYUDP_H
#define MYUDP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QAbstractSocket>

class myUDP : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit myUDP(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void sendMessage(QString Message);

signals:

public slots:
    void readyRead();

private:
    QUdpSocket *socket;
};

#endif // MYUDP_H
```

Файл myudp.cpp:

```
#include "myudp.h"

myUDP::myUDP(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
   socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
   socket -> bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 1234);
   connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}

void myUDP::sendMessage(QString Message)
{
   QByteArray Data;
   Data.append(Message);
   socket -> writeDatagram(Data, QHostAddress::LocalHost, 1234);
}

void myUDP::readyRead()
{
   QByteArray Buffer;
   Buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
   QHostAddress sender;
   quint16 senderPort;
   socket->readDatagram(Buffer.data(), Buffer.size(), &sender, &senderPort);
   qDebug() << "Message from: " << sender.toString();
   qDebug() << "Message port: " << senderPort;
   qDebug() << "Message: " << Buffer;

}
```

И, наконец, функция по нажатию кнопки для отправки сообщения в mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_sendButton_clicked()
{
    myUDP Server;

    myUDP client;

    client.sendMessage("Hello there!");
}
```

Однако при тестировании по нажатию на кнопку ничего не происходит, а в Application Output получаем сообщени:
`QNativeSocketEngine::writeDatagram() was called not in QAbstractSocket::BoundState or QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState`

Насколько я понял, программа не смогла подключиться к сокету. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Стоп, так вы же пытаетесь отправить сообщение на тот же адрес к которому бинжен сокет.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch  А как нужно сделать? Извините, это мой первый опыт работы с UDP в принципе (

Comment: в смысле как нужно? А что вы пытаетесь сделать то?

Comment: Пытаюсь отправить текстовое сообщение на все клиенты

Comment: на какие все клиенты? Если эти клиенты есть, то почему как по-вашему они должны получить сообщение когда вы отправляете его на тот же сокет с которого и отправляете?

Comment: А выше ошибки нет?

Comment: Вы бы для начала пример хотя бы 1в1 вбили, а потом пытались его переделать ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, ты хочешь сделать рассылку по UDP на все машины в данной сети. Если я правильно понимаю, то вот пример, который так работает. Для нормальной работы, это должны быть разные классы или как минимум разные сокеты! Нельзя отправлять данные на тот же сокет, который их отправляет.

Для подобной работы надо создать два класса, которые не будут зависеть друг от друга.

Первый класс, это сервер, который делает рассылку.

1) Это создание сервера (UdpServer.h)

```
class UdpServer : public QTextEdit 
{ 
      Q_OBJECT 

private: 
      QUdpSocket* m_pudp; 

public: 
      UdpServer(QWidget* pwgt = 0); 

private slots: 
      void slotSendDatagram(); 
};
```

2) Создание UdpServer.срр

```
UdpServer::UdpServer(QWidget* pwgt /*=О*/) : QTextEdit(pwgt) 
{ 
    setWindoWТitle("UdpServer"); 

    m_pudp = new QUdpSocket(this); 

    QТimer* ptimer = new QТimer(this); 
    ptimer->setInterval(500); 
    ptimer->start(); 

    connect(ptimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(slotSendDatagram())); 
}

void UdpServer::slotSendDatagram() 
{ 
     QByteArray baDatagram; 
     QDataStream out(&baDatagram, QIODevice::WriteOnly); 
     out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_3); 
     QDateTime dt = QDateTime::currentDateTime(); 
     append("Sent:" + dt.toString()); 
     out << dt; 
     m_pudp->writeDatagram(baDatagram, QHostAddress::LocalHost, 2424); 
}
```

Второй класс, это клиент, который получает рассылку. Но помните, чтобы машина смогла прочитать данные, у вас должны быть оба класса, но в разных программах.

1) UdpClient.h

```
class UdpClient : public QTextEdit 
{ 
     Q_OBJECT 

private: 
     QUdpSocket* m_pudp; 

public: 
     UdpClient(QWidget* pwgt = 0); 

private slots: 
     void slotProcessDatagrams(); 
};
```

2) UdpClient.cpp

```
UdpClient::UdpClient(QWidget* pwgt /*=О*/) : QTextEdit(pwgt) 
{ 
    setWindowТitle("UdpClient"); 

    m_pudp = new QUdpSocket(this); 
    m_pudp->bind(2424); 
    connect(m_pudp, SIGNAL(readyRead(}), SLOT(slotProcessDatagrams())); 
}

void UdpClient::slotProcessDatagrams() 
{ 
  QByteArray baDatagram; 

  do {

     baDatagrarn.resize(m_pudp->pendingDatagramSize()); 
     m_pudp->readDatagram(baDatagram.data(), baDatagram.size()); 

  } while(m_pudp->hasPendingDatagrams()); 

  QDateTime dateTime; 
  QDataStream in(&baDatagram, QIODevice::ReadOnly); 
  in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_3); 
  in >> dateTime; 
  append ("Received:" + dateTime. toString()); 
}
```

Одна программа сервер, другая клиент. Если реализуешь оба класса в одной программе, то это уже модель не клиент-->сервер, а P2P. Данный пример, надеюсь, поможет. Если нет, то пиши, чем смогу, тем помогу. Можешь посмотреть пусть и кривой, но все же пример моей реализации P2P в LAN сети, но уже с QTcpSocket (https://github.com/bogdyname/Freechat)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Наконец-то кто-то понял мой вопрос) Буду пробовать разобраться)

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз огромное! Благодаря Вашему примеру всё получилось :) Ура! Ура! Ура!